# How to count foreign keys and group by name? MongoDB map/reduce?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

How to make a query that returns counted post_ids objects with the 
name of the parent. How to do it in MongoDB? I switched from sql and I 
lost a lot of time on this problem.

one of the objects:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "4eb69c58b51ab1070e000024" ), 
  "name" : "ruby", 
  "post_ids" : [ 
    ObjectId( "4eb69c58b51ab1070e000023" ), 
    ObjectId( "4eb69c60b51ab1070e000026" ), 
    ObjectId( "4eb69c69b51ab1070e000027" ), 
    ObjectId( "4eb69c6fb51ab1070e000028" ), 
    ObjectId( "4eb69c7db51ab1070e000029" ) ] }
```

desired effect:

```
{"name":"ruby","count":"5", "post_ids":["4eb69c58b51ab1070e000023", 
"4eb69c60b51ab1070e000026", "4eb69c69b51ab1070e000027", 
"4eb69c6fb51ab1070e000028", "4eb69c7db51ab1070e000029"]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is untested, it might need some tweaking:

```
db.articles.group({
    key: { name:true },
    reduce: function(obj,prev) { prev.total_posts += obj.post_ids.length; },
    initial: { total_posts: 0 }
});
```